# Remove divider of last item / chid in <ion-list>

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When using `<ion-list>`, how can i set that the last item to not show a divider?

I have a list which has 2 `*ng-For` going through 2 arrays. The first array holds other arrays as elements.

The divider between elements of the first array are working alright. However, when the second array gets displayed, the last item also has a divider.

Setting the `no-lines` attribute removes all dividers between items, but i just want to remove the divider of the last one.

How the last item currently is displayed:

[image]

This is the desired result:

[image]

I already tried applying this style rule:

```
.md ion-list > .item:last-child, 
.md ion-list > .item-wrapper:last-child .item,
.wp ion-list > .item:last-child, 
.wp ion-list > .item-wrapper:last-child .item,
.ios ion-list > .item:last-child, 
.ios ion-list > .item-wrapper:last-child .item {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is my current code:

list.html

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let obj of TestObject.charListArray">
      {{obj.variable}}

      <ion-item *ngFor="let person of obj.contactArray">
        {{person.lastname}}, {{person.firstname}} <br> 
        {{person.email}} <br>
        {{person.company}}
      </ion-item>

    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

Class of testobject:

```
import { charSection } from '../home/charSection';
import { compactContact } from '../home/compactContact';

export class charList {
  charListArray: Array<charSection>;
  alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  chars = this.alphabet.split("");

  //Generates 26 charSection-Objects in this array
  constructor() {
    this.charListArray = [];
    for (let i in this.chars) {
      this.charListArray.push(new charSection(this.chars[i]));
    }
  }
```

CharSection-class:

```
import { compactContact } from '../home/compactContact';

export class charSection {
  contactArray: Array<compactContact>;

  constructor(public char: string) {
    this.contactArray = [];
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added more of my code. If anything else is missing or the information provided is bad / chaotic / too unstructured, i can delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. This worked for me:

```
ion-item:last-child {
    --border-width: 0;
    --border-color: transparent;
}
```